# Dynamic CheckBoxes infinitely being added every click on TextView

Tags: android, xml, checkbox, android-linearlayout, textview

I am new to Android Studio/Development, but not programming itself. I am struggling with the syntax (as I do think it is my problem) yet I cannot find a solution anywhere on here or on Google. I have this 2nd activity named FilterActivity. FilterActivity currently has 2 TextViews. Both create dynamic CheckBoxes. Right now, I only have one doing this so I can get one right before I go onto another. Here's the issue, I click on the TextView to get the dynamically created CheckBox and it shows perfectly fine. However, clicking on it again just adds the same values until it appears to completely fill the parent via xml.

No matter what I search, what I do, it all does the same exact thing. I know, I have nothing for onCheckedChanged, but I have previously before and it did not work either. So question(s), should I not be using LinearLayout and do like a container of sorts? There will be a decently big database for the checkboxes (500+) so I was thinking I would have to implement ScrollView at some point. Also, if LinearLayout is the correct way to go, what am I doing wrong? I am just completely spinning and I know it should not be this hard.

Thank you to anyone that gives feedback!

Here's XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="xxx.AppEx.FilterActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_filter">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/firstView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/secondView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AllTextView"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="All"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:height="50dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/firstView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAllCaps="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DisTextView"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Dis"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:height="50dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/firstView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAllCaps="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/CheckBoxLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/secondView">
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the main code:

```
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.CheckBox;
    import android.widget.CompoundButton;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.content.Intent;

    public class FilterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    LinearLayout CheckBoxLayout;
    CheckBox checkBox;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_filter);
        CheckBoxLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.CheckBoxLayout);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final TextView AllTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AllTextView);
        AllTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                AllTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                onAllClick();
            }
        });

        TextView DisTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DisTextView);
        DisTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //onAllClick();
            }
        });
    }

    public void onAllClick()
    {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        dummy();
    }

    public void dummy()
    {
        String[] array = new String[]
                {
                        "Rice", "Beans"
                };

        LinearLayout CheckBoxLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.CheckBoxLayout);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
            checkBox.setText(array[i]);
            CheckBoxLayout.addView(checkBox);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

    }
    }
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to achieve. If you have larger number of checkboxes to add, its better to use a ListView/RecyclerView/GridView.

Comment: I'm trying to not have the CheckBoxes to keep adding. It's the same thing over and over. So if I have 2 CheckBoxes to add, it will keep adding until it can no longer fit in the Layout. I want it to stop adding the same CheckBoxes. 

The only way it does this is if I clicked on TextView again. If I have 500 CheckBoxes, I do not want the same 500 values print out again.

Comment: Basically saying, I only want these CheckBoxes to print the values once, not twice if I keep clicking on the TextView. Ideally, it would either bring the values back up again OR nothing at all, just show the same values. I want to keep on the same activity.

Comment: just put a simple condition in your onClick method. ``if(!stopAdding) { onAllClick(); stopAdding = true; }``. Or you want something else that I still didn't understand.

Comment: I think this is what I would want. A conditional or a loop to check if the TextView has been clicked. I have thought about something like what you provided, but with the correct way to go about it. I am just at a complete blank with it.

Comment: ok. then I think this is the simplest solution.

Comment: Is the stopAdding proper syntax? It does not appear to be.